# how to remove duplicate data in mysql without primary key and keep the latest one

Tags: mysql

i have spend 6 hours to figure out this but i still cannot find the solution, here's the table:[image]

i use row_number(), CTE also cannot solve this issue. i just merely want to delete the repeated date with old data and keep the latest data, i cant keep the new data if i delete count>1 and row_number>1, please help.

i have tried below but it keeps my data all deleted:

```
delete from aaa where date in (select date from (select *,row_number() over (partition by date order by date) as rn from aaa)t where rn=1);
```

Comment: If MySql supported updatable CTEs this would be easily possible using `row_number` as suggested. However in MySql you *have* to join to the original table to perform a delete or update which means you have NO way to identify unique columns. Adding an auto increment ID to the table is really the only solution.

Comment: yes.. you are right.. i should not spend 6 hours stubborn on this.. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is that your data is completely identical. There is nothing to distinguish any other record from the next one. If you have more columns that are not displayed here, that would open up some additional options that aren't currently possible with the data set you have posted here. There are a couple options.

1. Add a primary key (or at last a running index) to each row so that there is something to distinguish one entry from the next.
2. Select distinct results into a temporary table. Delete everything from your existing table. And then re-insert everything from your temporary table into your existing table. Then drop your temporary table. Do your delete and insert in a single transaction so that you do not have the table temporarily empty and visible to other transactions (if we assume that your other parallel transactions will only read committed data).

If you actually have more columns, then you could group by and select the min() value from the additional column to help you distinguish them. Then you delete everthing that does not belong to this data set (your duplicate records + the min(column_that_shows_a_difference).

However, you really should add a primary key to your table (even if it is simply a auto-generated identity column that isn't reflected in your application data model). When you have a business key that tells you something is (or ought to be) unique, then you should additionally create a unique-constraint.

Comment: yes that's my final solution for option1 which is adding the primary key. but I hope there is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a delete with join based  on subqoery for not matching max date

```
delete aaa
from aaa 
inner join (
    select aaa.ticker, date 
    from aaa 
    left join (
        select aaa.ticker, max(date) as max_date 
        from aaa 
        group by ticker
        ) t on aaa.ticker = t.ticker and aaa.date = t.max_date 
        where t.max_date is null
) t2 on t2.ticker = aaa.ticker
    and t2.date = aaa.date
```

Comment: thanks for the code but i not sure why i got the syntax error: delete from aaa inner join (select ticker, date from aaa left join (select ticker, max(date) as max_date from aaa group by ticker) t on aaa.ticker=t.ticker and aaa.date = t.max_date where t.max_date is null) t2 on t2.ticker = aaa.ticker and t2.date = aaa.date;

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join (select ticker, date from aaa left join (select ticker, max(date) as ' at line 1

Comment: answer  updated ..  left me know

Comment: ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'Ticker' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Looks like we need a new name for ticker in subquery but was used to group by it.. hmm

Comment: answer  updated ..  with full reference column name

Comment: Thanks for your effort and several tries.... but the result only show the duplicate latest date after executed... looks like primary key is still needed to make it simple.. haha

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the only solution with adding primary key for auto increment with below code executed:

```
delete t1 
from aaa t1 
inner join aaa t2 
where t1.id < t2.id and t1.date = t2.date;
```